# Is there any change in reputation points to upvote a post after the "Question askers were awarded"?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

When I started participating in Ask Ubuntu, the reputation required to upvote a post was 15.

With the recent change in reputation earned from an upvote on question after [the question askers were awarded](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/), is the 15 mark still there or changed?

Comment: [Still 15](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: thank you @ Kulfy.. is there atleast any reference for it if its unchanged along with Q = A rep?

Comment: There ain't any reference to that except the help center AFAIK.

Comment: Thank You @Kulfy..

Comment: Kulfy for 2020!

Comment: @DKBose.. what's that I didn't understand above comment..

Comment: Getting 15 rep was never hard. :-)

Comment: @Pilot6 very well comment.. kindly see the edit to Q

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no evidence that any privilege thresholds have changed.

See https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges.